# Is it possible to make this specific shape with css3 only?

Tags: html, css

[image: the shape]

I know it's possible to make, however i don't really know how to.
I'm also trying to make the shape scaleable.

EDIT: Sorry for the bad question guys, i should have put more emphasis on the fact i want it to be scalable. I don't want the divs to fall under eachother once the frame width gets smaller.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: if you don't mind,could you share your code or whatever you have done so far!!!!!

Comment: yes it is possible, create  a line then spread out divs with border-radius 50%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using `border-radius`

**HTML :**

```
<div id="a">
    <div class="b">
    </div>
    <div class="b">
    </div>
    <div class="b">
    </div>
    <div class="b">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#a{
    width:75%;
    height:5px;
    background:grey;
    margin-top:30px;
    position:relative;
}
.b{
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:-13px;

}
.b:first-child{
    left:0;
}
.b:last-child{
    right:0;
}
.b:nth-child(2){
    left:28%;
}
.b:nth-child(3){
    right:28%;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/sKXX2/6/)

**Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve something like this using [border-radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) for the circle and either heights or border sizing for the lines. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/YYRcu/) a very quick fiddle of how you could do it. It's always good to show what you've attempted first though, or what kinds of things you have been searching. Even if your code is wrong, it shows you tried.

```
.circle {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 25px;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:50px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px -4px;
}
.line {
    width:60px;
    height:4px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a bad question because you didn't tell us what have you tried so far, yet, it's so simple I had to give you a hand: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/72BpF/)

A circle can be made with a square div with `border-radius: 100%`. A line is a simple div. Put them one after another with `float: left`.

```
.circle{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
    float: left;
}

.line{
    margin-top: 18px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
    float: left;    
}
```

Of course, you can do it in many more ways.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/72BpF/1/ change your border-radius: 20px;

Comment: Why should I change the `border-radius`? In your method, once you changed the `width` and `height` yo must change the `border-radius` while in my method you don't

Comment: oh oops sorry. That was my browser fault. i'm using the older chrome version. i saw the rectangular box. so, i thought it wrongly... your answer is good.. +1 from me..

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) on how to do it using HTML5 and CSS.

Comment: You could have tried to make one from your side

Comment: Where would be the learning curve in that? Surely the community is about guiding people in the right direction so they actually pick up some new skills?